# angularjs directive not run going into

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Ok I have an issue with directive that lay on ng-repeat but as well without at not running.

so this is the come

main template:

```
 <div ng-if="[%!query.$resolved%]">
    <div ng-cloak ng-show="query.mission_type == 0" class="animate-show">
        <div ng-include src="'Interctive/templates/missions/plugins/open_question_plugin.html'"></div>
    </div>

    <div ng-cloak ng-show="query.mission_type == 1"  class="animate-show">
        [%query.type_plugin%]33
         <div ng-include src="'Interctive/templates/missions/plugins/american_question_plugin.html'"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Second template:

```
<div>
    <div mission_item dataitem="query.forms[0]" >[%query.forms%]</div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in query.forms" >
        <div mission_item dataitem="item" ng-model="item">[%item%]--</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The directive loading:

```
define([
    // Standard Libs
    'jquery'     // lib/jquery/jquery
    , 'Angular'    // lib/angular/angular
    , 'directives/missions/mission_item_handler'
    // Application Widgets

], function ($, angular,mission_item_handler_directive) {
    "use strict";
    Console.group("Entering Widgets module.");

    var directives = {
        "mission_item":mission_item_handler_directive
    };
    Console.info("Registered directives: ", directives);

    var initialize = function (angModule) {
        _.each(directives, function (filter, name) {
            angModule.directive(name, filter[1]);
        })
        Console.debug("Custom widgets initialized.");
    }

    Console.groupEnd();
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

the directive code:

```
define([
    // Standard Libs
    'jquery',
    'text!templates/missions/plugins/open/field_text.html',
    'text!templates/missions/plugins/open/field_image.html',
    'text!templates/missions/plugins/open/field_youtube.html',
    'text!templates/missions/plugins/open/field_textbox.html'
], function ($, field_text_template, field_image_template, field_youtube_template, field_textbox_template) {
    "use strict";
    Console.group("Entering Directive Open Question Items Field.");
    var directive = ['mission_item', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: false,
            order: 9999,
            scope: { dataitem: "="},
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                Console.log("Entered Field Item" , scope);
                var templateFn;

                attrs.$observe('item', function (newValue) {
                    console.log(newValue)
                })
                /*if (item.type == "header")
                    templateFn = $compile(field_text_template);
                if (item.type == "image")
                    templateFn = $compile(field_image_template);
                if (item.type == "textbox")
                    templateFn = $compile(field_textbox_template);
                templateFn(scope);*/
            }
        };
    }];
    Console.groupEnd();
    return directive;
});
```

now my main issue is that even if i do  breakpoints within the directive its loaded but not running mean i see the output of the system that he been loaded but when i put at within the ng-reapeat(or without) its stop working and have not idea why

any pointers?

Comment: and when you just put ``` <div  mission_item="mission_item" item="item" ng-model="item"></div> 22``` in the template everything works as expected? broken only in ```ng-repeat```? bTW: what is the 22 doing outside the div - a typo I guess?

Comment: the 22 its just see the repeat works that all(and he dose)

Answer (score 0):

just Noticed that you set an `order` is this an old way to set `priority` ?(most of the directive declaration look a little weird to me, so maybe I'm missing something)

If order is indeed priority then maybe you should set it lower then `ng-repeat` priority which is 1000, so it would compile after ng-repeat and would have `item` available. just a hunch

Answer (score 0):

ok after i found out the  directive and ng-repeat basically not working good together i redesign the system and added directive  that will passed on the object and after at  a i added the template within the directive (kill one of the templates yaya!).
after that i change the directive  definition into:

```
        restrict: 'E',
        priority: 0, //must be 0 or transclusion fails
        replace: true, //must be true
        transclusion:true,
```

after that all work ng-repeat and directive  then u do at wrong just use directive  more smart and less overhead:) 
well this what i found out